# Cannot download music on iPhone

Tags: iphone, music

I have Apple Music subscription. I am able to hear and download music on my Mac, but I cannot download music on my iPhone. I can hear it on iPhone, but when I press download I see endless round animation.

Here is what I have already tried to do:

- Reinstall Apple Music.
- Use different WiFi and cellular network.
- Reboot iPhone.

My settings:

- Music - Show Apple Music = On
- Music - Sync Library = One
- Music - Mobile Data = On
- Music - Downloaded Music → Zero KB
- Music - Optimize Storage = Off
- Music - Automatic Downloads = On/Off (tried both)

What can I check more ? May be I something miss ?

Comment: How much free space on your iPhone. It may be that Apple Music requires a certain amount before it will download songs.

Comment: No, I have more that 100 Gb free on iPhone.

Comment: what model iPhone do you have?

Comment: @jmh, iPhone 11 Pro.